# Is there a way to clear modules in VSCode?

Tags: python, error-handling, module, visual-studio-code

I accidentally named a file `bokeh.py` and now it's telling me bokeh is not a module. I renamed it and tried deleting it and making a new one that's not named to confuse VSCode, but it's still giving me the same error. Opening a new window works tho. But I kind of want to keep all my files in one window and I don't want to restart the whole thing just to have it not throw the "not a module" error because there's a lot of stuff that will be lost and need to rerun. Is there a way to just clear that particular issue?

Comment: What exactly is telling you that "bokeh is not a module"? Is it Pylint? Is it the language server?

Comment: @Brett It's the error I get when I try to run the code.

Comment: so you're getting an ImportError? If that's the case that has nothing really to do with VS Code since it doesn't influence the interpreter that way.